# Numpy in Python script fails to import when called from the command prompt

Tags: python, excel, vba, numpy

I am trying to run a simple Python script from Excel by calling the script in a VBA macro. Whenever I run the script from Spyder, it executes perfectly. However, when I call the script from Excel using VBA, it fails. This only occurs when I import Numpy or Pandas (I haven't tried other libraries) into the script.

The VBA macro that calls the script is here:

```vb
Sub RunPythonScript2()

'Declare our variables
Dim RetVal As String
Dim exe As String
Dim python As String
Dim paths As String

exe = "C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe"
python = "C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Reference Documents\Python\Excel and Python\03 Script.py"
paths = """" & exe & """" & " " & """" & python & """"

RetVal = Shell(paths, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

The Python script that works is here:

```
import win32com.client

excelapp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = excelapp.Workbooks(1)
sht = wb.Worksheets(1)

sht.Range('A1').Value = "Hello World "
```

Everything so far works just fine. However, if I add a statement to import Numpy or Pandas to the python script, then I can no longer successfully call the script from Excel. I can, however, run the script from Spyder and produce the expected result.

I originally called the `python.exe`, but when I used:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

I saw that Spyder was calling the `pythonw.exe`. It doesn't seem to matter whether I call `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe`.

I don't receive any error messages when I import Numpy and run the script. The result is that nothing is printed to Excel.

I am using the following package versions on Windows 10, 64 bit

1. python version 3.7.3
2. numpy version 1.16.2
3. pywin32 version 223
4. Anaconda version custom (because I installed xlwings and geopandas)

I would like to be able to print something like this to Excel:

```
sht.Range('A1').Value = np.pi
```

EDITS-------------------------------------
I also confirmed that it is related to Numpy. I was able to `import sys` in my Python code without any problem, but I am still having issues with Numpy and Pandas.

Other people have managed to run this code successfully, so I suspect it must be some sort of environment related problem. However, I don't really know how to manage my environments.

See this youtube video and comments for an example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVNeufjrx8M&list=PLcFcktZ0wnNnf4eh5ObzPzoLFOzTiFVKa&index=6&t=0s

I have tried a clean install of Anaconda, and I am still having the issue. Here is what `conda info` returns:

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\<user>\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\<user>\.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.14
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       base environment : C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\<user>\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\<user>\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.14 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.14393
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

This same problem occurs on both my computer at home and at my computer at work.

Comment: What is the executable line on command prompt you use to execute? You can try it will `os.system()` function.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine in my System even if i Import `numpy` & `Pandas`

Comment: See here (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FsLvpJ-F3oNY3hZF8z0dHvim4QehooJV)

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou - I am not sure what you are asking. The windows command prompt function is given in my VBA code in the Shell() command. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Mikku - Other people have tried it as well, and it worked for them. See SigmaCoding's youtube video and comments: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVNeufjrx8M&list=PLcFcktZ0wnNnf4eh5ObzPzoLFOzTiFVKa&index=6&t=0s

Comment: @Miku - And you did run it through Excel, right? Because it works fine for me too when I run it through Spyder.

Comment: Where are you using the pandas in your code?

Comment: Why you want to use only excel app where as directly you can call the excel with [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) ?

Comment: @AmazingThings- I am not using Pandas right now, but I would like to be able to, and I can’t. I want to be able to call Python from Excel so I can build macros for work that are powered by everything Python can do.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's walk through some changes that we need to make to your code. I think the issue is coming from the fact that when you're referencing the Workbooks collection you're using the index method vice the key method. This can get you into trouble if you have a personal Macro Workbook.

The index is determined in the order in which the workbooks are opened, and the Personal Macro Workbook is **ALWAYS** opened first. This usually has unintended consequences, so I tell people to just use the name of the workbook. Change the following:

Old:

`wb = excelapp.Workbooks(1)`

New:

`wb = excelapp.Workbooks("myWorkbook.xlsm")`

Additionally, I think if we remove some of the quotes it should work fine. I rewrote each line so it's encapsulated with triple quotes.

Old:

```
exe = "C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe"
python = "C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Reference Documents\Python\Excel and Python\03 Script.py"
paths = """" & exe & """" & " " & """" & python & """"
```

New:

```
Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")    
    exe = """C:\Users\<USER>\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe"""    
    python = """C:\Users\<USER>\OneDrive\myScript.py"""
    objShell.Run exe & python
```

Give this a try and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks. This didn't fix the problem, but I do like the cleaner concatenation. I am trying a clean install of Anaconda...

Comment: The clean install didn't fix the problem either.  )-:

Answer (score 0):

---

Latest Update 9/24/19

This problem and its solution are best described here:

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#shell-commands-open-from-the-wrong-location

The problem is with the PATH variable, but it can be easily fixed by deactivating and reactivating your environment. Simply adding the location to the path doesn't necessarily fix the issue - it didn't for me. Open up anaconda prompt and `deactivate base` and then `reactivate base`.

The issue is also described here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1413313/importerror-missing-required-dependencies-numpy

Resetting my Anaconda version back to 5.2.0 with `conda install anaconda=5.2.0` did work, but I have no idea why.